# How to find number of variation of spintax combination in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Suppose I have a spintax of:

```
A boy already has {a banana|an orange|an apple}, but he still want to eat more {ice cream|yogurt|cookie}.
```

How I can write javascript or php to calculate the number of all possible combination of the spintax.

The concept is to count for the phases which are  separated by pipe in each curly pairs, and multiply them together, but I don't know how to count that phases, could you please suggest me?

I tried to search for a solution, but could not find anything.

Comment: How much " but he still want to eat more {ice cream|yogurt|cookie}."? or not limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a='A boy already has {a banana|an orange|an apple}, but he still wants to eat more {ice cream|yogurt|cookies} before going to {school|college}.';
var h=a.match(/{[^}]+}/g).map(m=>m.split('|').length).reduce((p,v)=>p*v);
console.log('There are '+h+' possible combinations.')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The script first finds all `{}` sections and collects them in an array. This is then scanned with `map()` to `split()` each element with `|`. The count of the elements in the resulting sub-array is then returned and eventually all counts are combined in a product using `reduce()`.